# Are the Entity functions broken?

Tags: entity

When I try to use any version of the `Entity` functions, the function is returned as if it were undefined.  For example, `EntityList["Planet"]` returns `EntityList[Planet]`. The help examples don't work either.  Is this happening to everyone, or just me?

Comment: On my machine, it works fine (Mathematica 10.0.1)

Comment: I think there is nothing broken in the Entity functions. It's most likely a problem with files in your paclets folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
<<EntityFramework`
```

Comment: That did it! I hope that I didn't cause problems by deleting the Paclets folders.

Comment: It works, but how to make it default?

Answer (score 3):

I'm running V10.1 on OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite). I ran into this problem about two weeks ago. I solved it by shutting down *Mathematica*, throwing the Paclets folder found in ~/Library/Mathematica/ into the Trash, and restarting *Mathematica*. After restarting, I tried the same "Planet" example as you did and it worked (after downloading some new paclets).

I have not had any trouble with `Entity` expressions since.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I deleted the Paclets folders in the ProgramData and AppData>Roaming folders, but it didn't fix the problem.  I also did a "clean restart" of Mathematica, but that didn't help either.

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe. Sorry it didn't work for you. Are you sure the packet folder you deleted is the only one on your system? I don't recognize the path you mentioned. I guess you aren't on OS X.